# How to creat a Splunk bubble diagram from timechart

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-calculation, splunk-formula

I am trying to create a bubblechart based on this search, also seen in image below.

```
source="*wineventlog:security" sourcetype="*wineventlog:security" EventCode=4624 OR 4625 OR 4649 OR 4724 OR 4732 OR 4740| timechart span=1h count(EventCode) by EventCode
```

I have tried different methods to create something similar to the edited bubblechart image below, but with no success so far. I hope someone here can possibly help me achieve this, if it is even possible?

I can see that i probably would need to get the eventcodes in a own columns, and probably the same with the count...but how?

[image: Splunk search]

[image: Bubblechart]

Answer (score 0):

You've got two issues.

First, the `OR` has to still be using the field name for the comparisons (`EventCode=4724 OR EventCode=4740...`). Or you can use `EventCode IN("val1","val2"...)`

Second, you can simplify the `count(EventCode)` to `count`.

Try this:

```
source="*wineventlog:security" sourcetype="*wineventlog:security" EventCode IN("4624","4625","4649","4724","4732","4740")
| timechart span=1h count by EventCode
```

Comment: Turns out it was not an bubblediagram i was trying to replicate but a punchhole diagram,  after realising...the rest was easy :-p